# Equivalent (?) definitions of Markov property

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb N}$ be a stochastic process on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ with countable state space $S$.

$(A)$:

Let $n \ge 1, A_1,\ldots,A_{n+1}\subseteq S, P[X_n \in A_n, \ldots X_1 \in A_1]>0$

$\mathbb P[X_{n+1} \in A_{n+1}|X_n \in A_n, \ldots , X_1 \in A_1]=\mathbb P[X_{n+1} \in A_{n+1}|X_n \in A_n]$

$(B)$

Let $n \ge 1, t_1<t_2<\ldots <t_{n+1} \in \mathbb N, A_1,\ldots,A_{n+1}\subseteq S, P[X_{t_n} \in A_n, \ldots X_{t_1} \in A_1]>0$

$\mathbb P[X_{t_{n+1}} \in A_{n+1}|X_{t_n} \in A_n, \ldots , X_{t_1} \in A_1]=\mathbb P[X_{t_{n+1}} \in A_{n+1}|X_{t_n} \in A_n]$

Clearly, $B$ implies $A$.

Does $A$ imply $B$ as well? If yes, how can I show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, A) does imply B). All you have to do is to take some of the sets $A_i$ to be $S$. (You can take some simple cases to see what is happening).

A typical example of how this works: $$P(X_5\in A_5|X_1\in A_1, X_4\in A_4)\equiv P(X_5\in A_5|X_1\in A_1,X_2 \in S,X_3 \in S, X_4\in A_4)$$ $$ =P(X_5\in A_5|X_4\in A_4)$$

by A).

Comment: $S$ is countable so the $A_i \subseteq S$ have to be countable as well, so we can't simply choose  $A_i=\mathbb R$?

Comment: @user711482b I have replaced $\mathbb R$ by $S$ in my answer.

Comment: Okay, but I don't really understand it yet. If we choose for example $A_1=S$ then we have $\mathbb P[X_{n+1} \in A_{n+1}|X_n \in A_n, \ldots , X_1 \in A_1]= \mathbb P[X_{n+1} \in A_{n+1}|X_n \in A_n, \ldots , X_2 \in A_2]$ and so on. But how does this help me to show B?

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: When you replace $X_n \in A_n$ by $X_n \in S$ you can  simply omit the condition $X_n \in S$  because this puts no restriction on $X_n$. @user711482

Comment: @KaboMurpy Yes but I can't simply choose $A_n$ as I want, can I? They are arbitrary

Comment: @user711482 Only those corresponding to $t_1,t_1,..$ cannot be chosen the way we want. The others can be taken to be $S$. I suggest you take  a simple example say $t_1=1, t_2=3, t_3=6$, take $n=6$ in (A) and see what is happening.

Comment: @KaboMurpy I don't get it. So using your example we have at the LHS of (B) $P[X_{t_7}\in A_7|X_{t_6}\in A_6,\ldots,X_{t_4}\in A_4, X_6 \in A_3, X_3 \in A_2, X_1 \in A_1]$. Now I think you mean that we choose $A_6=A_5=A_4=S$, so we have $P[X_{t_7}\in A_7|X_6 \in A_3, X_3 \in A_2, X_1 \in A_1]$ but what now?